# Android CountDownTimer - adding time results in multiple timers running

Tags: java, android, timer

Im trying to make it so that my timer adds 5 seconds every time I press the button. I've learnt that I need to cancel the previous timer and create a new one for it to work the way I want it to. When I press the button once, the timer adds 5 seconds and everything works fine as its supposed to. My problem arises when I press the button multiple times. The timer will flicker between many different timers instead of staying on the latest one. Every time I press the button, another timer is flickering on the display. Its almost as if the program doesnt cancel the previous timers and just creates a new every time. I'd really appreciate some help on this. Thanks guys!

```
import android.os.CountDownTimer;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    int scoreTeamA = 0;
    String countDownTimer;
    long millisUntilFinishedInt = 5000;
    long milliseconds;
    long seconds;
    long totalAddedTime = 0;
    TextView text1;

    MyCount counter = new MyCount(millisUntilFinishedInt + totalAddedTime,17);

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        text1=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.team_a_score);
        counter.start();
    }

    public class MyCount extends CountDownTimer {

        public MyCount(long millisInFuture, long countDownInterval) {
            super(millisInFuture, countDownInterval);
        }

        @Override
        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {

            millisUntilFinishedInt = millisUntilFinished;
            seconds = millisUntilFinishedInt/1000;
            milliseconds = millisUntilFinishedInt-(millisUntilFinishedInt/1000)*1000;
            countDownTimer = "TIME: " + seconds + "." + milliseconds ;
           text1.setText(countDownTimer);
        }

        @Override
        public void onFinish() {
            countDownTimer = "TIME'S UP!";
            text1.setText(countDownTimer);
        }
    }

    public void timerCreation (){
        counter.cancel();
        MyCount counter = new MyCount(millisUntilFinishedInt + 5000,1);
        counter.start();
    }

    //method that is called when button is pressed
    public void threePoints (View v) {
        timerCreation();
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this

```
public void timerCreation (){
    counter.cancel();
    MyCount counter = new MyCount(millisUntilFinishedInt + 5000,1);
    counter.start();
}
```

Into this

```
public void timerCreation (){
    counter.cancel();
    counter = new MyCount(millisUntilFinishedInt + 5000,1);
    counter.start();
}
```

With your current implementation, you are cancelling your member variable `counter`. Then you create a local variable with the same name and start that one. The next time you press your button, your member variable `counter` gets cancelled again (which is already cancelled) in order to create a new `MyCount` object and start that one. That is why you are ending up with multiple timers

Comment: This worked flawlessly. Thank you so much. Can't believe it was such a simple fix.

Answer (score 0):

**Changes:** increase interal to **50** but but mandatory.

```
   MyCount counter = new MyCount(millisUntilFinishedInt + totalAddedTime, 50);
```

Align text view gravity to left `android:gravity="left"` so user cant feel its new timmer.

**Tested Working Demo**

**MainActivity**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    Context context;
    int scoreTeamA = 0;
    String countDownTimer;
    long millisUntilFinishedInt = 5000;
    long milliseconds;
    long seconds;
    long totalAddedTime = 0;
    TextView text1;
    MyCount counter = new MyCount(millisUntilFinishedInt + totalAddedTime, 50);

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        context = this;

        text1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.foodName);
        text1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                timerCreation();
            }
        });
    }

    public class MyCount extends CountDownTimer {

        public MyCount(long millisInFuture, long countDownInterval) {
            super(millisInFuture, countDownInterval);
        }

        @Override
        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {

            millisUntilFinishedInt = millisUntilFinished;
            seconds = millisUntilFinishedInt / 1000;
            milliseconds = millisUntilFinishedInt - (millisUntilFinishedInt / 1000) * 1000;
            countDownTimer = "TIME: " + seconds + "." + milliseconds;
            text1.setText(countDownTimer);
        }

        @Override
        public void onFinish() {
            countDownTimer = "TIME'S UP!";
            text1.setText(countDownTimer);
        }
    }

    public void timerCreation() {
        counter.cancel();
        MyCount counter = new MyCount(millisUntilFinishedInt + 5000, 1);
        counter.start();
    }

    //method that is called when button is pressed
    public void threePoints(View v) {
        timerCreation();
    }
}
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/base"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_margin="10dp"
    android:background="@color/white"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:weightSum="10">


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/foodName"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:hint="Food name"
        android:gravity="left"
        android:inputType="textCapWords"
        android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
        android:textColorHint="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
        android:textSize="32sp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```